# KeyListener not responding after value modification in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

I'm writing a program in java that opens a window and detects keystrokes.

However, there is one fatal problem. if i modify the value in TextField, KeyListener will not work again. Here is the code that summarizes the problem situation I ran into:

```java
    
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    private Main(){

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500,500);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));

        JPanel textFieldPanel = new JPanel();
        textFieldPanel.setFocusable(true);
        textFieldPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { //it is not responding after value modification in JTextField...
                System.out.println("test");
            }
        });
        textFieldPanel.add(textField);
        add(textFieldPanel);

        pack();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

I want to make it get a KeyListener even while entering a value, And also want to know why the listener is disabled.

I've disabled the fields via the disable and re-enable method, but the KeyListener still doesn't work.

```java
        textField.addActionListener(e -> {
            textField.setEnabled(false);
            textField.setEnabled(true);
        });
```

How can I make it want to receive only the shortcuts, without the help of any external classes?
Since I added it directly to the JFrame, it doesn't seem to be a focusing issue.

Comment: can you provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: yes, You can create an object in the main class and run the code I showed you right away and No additional code is required.

Comment: your code works just fine. Your problem is not that the Listener doesn't work, it's that you added that KeyListener to the Frame. Since your textfield covers the entire frame, it's not possible for your frame itself to be selected. Add your KeyListener to your textField instead of to your Frame. Since you want the Listener to be triggered on an update of the field, that's what you should 've done either way.

Comment: I'm not sure what is you're trying to achieve, but generally speaking, a `KeyListener` on a text component is a bad idea.  Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760311/performing-a-certain-task-after-pressing-ctrl-alt-backspace/12763850#12763850) would work better

Comment: [Key capture example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46985936/using-keybinding-and-action-map-in-java-for-shortcut-keys-for-buttons/46986203#46986203)

Comment: _want to receive only the shortcuts_ which short-custs?

Comment: as-is, it either describes a typo-like error (adding the listener to the wrong component) or a keylistener is the wrong approach.

Comment: Just so we're a little clear - there are a number of possible ways to for monitor keyboard input, some are better then others, but without more clarity , it's impossible to to provide you with a decent amount of direction

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order for your Listener to be applicable to your textField, you need to change this:

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { //it is not responding after value modification in JTextField...
                System.out.println("test");
            }
        });
```

into this:

```
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { //it is not responding after value modification in JTextField...
                System.out.println("test");
            }
        });
```

At current, your Listener is attached to your Frame, which is completely covered by the textField.

Comment: So, if I understand the question correctly, if the OP was to add a button or another text field, this solution would stop working

Comment: @MadProgrammer why would this stop working? Indeed, it wouldn't work when changing the value on a second field (if added), but if he wants it to be executed on a second field as well, he can easily externalize the implementation of the KeyAdapter() and add that as Listener to both the fields. At this point, he just wanted the keyPressed to be executed when he changed the value in his original field

Comment: My problem is, I don't know "why" they want to do what they want to do and a `KeyListener`, generally, isn't a good solution, especially on `JTextField`s.  The OPs original problem was caused by the focus related drawbacks of `KeyListener` to start with - but I don't have enough context of the intention to provide a suitable answer to the problem which doesn't create more issues

Comment: I agree I don't understand the why neither, but it was pretty straightforward to get it to work.

Comment: Sure - but without more context, all you might have done is delayed them until they find another issue (with this approach) and force them to ask another question.  Would have been better to seek more clarification and/or closed the question as "vague" - IMHO

Comment: well, fully agree with @MadProgrammer - as long as we don't know the _exact_ requirement (the _want ... shortcuts_ might be reason to assume that they need a broader approach) this is fixing a potential typo-like error (adding the listener to the wrong component).